# Why BoxLayout is taking extra space?

Tags: java, swing, awt, layout-manager, boxlayout

I am working on a Client-Server Chatting Application in which I am trying to create Speech Bubble like we have in WhatsApp

I want to show sent messages on the right side of the frame and received messages on the left side of the frame, I am trying to achieve this using `BoxLayout` but it is taking extra space (like in picture below)
[image]

This is what I have done till now

```
a1.setLayout(new BoxLayout(a1, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
JPanel p1 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
JPanel p2 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
```

The extra space you see between the two messages is because of `BoxLayout` which I am using
What to do in this case? and any alternatives how can we achieve this by not using `BoxLayout`?

Comment: Create a JPanel that uses the FlowLayout, and put the JPanel that uses the BoxLayout inside the FlowLaypout JPanel.

Comment: The problem is that a BoxLayout will allow components to grow in size (up to their maximum size) when there is extra space available. A panel using the FlowLayout will respect the preferred size of the components added to it.

Comment: @camickr Yeah! exactly this is the issue with BoxLayout, And I am having a hard time solving this. Will you please take out some time and elaborate the solution. It will be very kind.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc After doing this, message is not printing on screen. Will do some more changes and check if that solution works or not –

Comment: *and elaborate the solution* - thought I did. The FlowLayout will display the panel with the BoxLayout at its preferred size. If there is extra space on the frame, then the panel with the FlowLayout will increase in size but this will have no effect on the BoxLayout since it will always be displayed at its preferred size.

Comment: @camickr I have edited the answer, will you please check where I am doing it wrong

Comment: In the future post an [mre] demonstrating the problem. My answer is in the form of an "MRE".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the FlowLayout respected the preferred height, but it also respected the preferred width.

Instead you need a layout that will:

1. respect the height of the component you add to the BoxLayout
2. fills the width of the available space.

You can use a `BorderLayout` for this:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SSCCE extends JPanel
{
    public SSCCE()
    {
        setLayout( new BorderLayout() );

        Box vertical = Box.createVerticalBox();
        add(vertical, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            JPanel left = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
            left.add(new JLabel("left message " + i), BorderLayout.LINE_START);
            vertical.add( left );
            JPanel right = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
            right.add(new JLabel("right message " + i), BorderLayout.LINE_END);
            vertical.add( right );
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SSCCE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( new JScrollPane(new SSCCE()) );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater( () -> createAndShowGUI() );
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked, thankyou so much. You are a legend bro. You saved my hours of frustation